# How to specify types, default values and validators for Vue component data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following component and would like to set the type and default value for `editing`, which gets toggled to display either `Item` values or an `<input>`:

```js
    Vue.component('item', {
            props: {
                'item': Item,
                'editing': {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false
                },
            },
            data: function() {
                return {
                    _cachedItemText: '',
                }
            },
            methods: {
```

The following warning results when the value of `editing` gets toggled by pressing an `Edit` button (not shown).

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "editing"

In the `Props` [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation), there's an example showing how to set the type, default value and validator for a prop. Is there an analogous way to set these attributes for a data item?

Also, I'm not passing `editing` in from the parent component, so I don't think it really *needs* to be a prop instead of a data item.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `item` both as a component name and a prop name.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim I wondered about that, too. Maybe it should be "item-component" or something.

Answer (score 0):

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "editing"

I see. You're passing the `prop` `editing` from the parent component to the child component. Then, in the child component, you use that `prop` and definitely have a method that ***mutate*** that `prop` `editing` directly.

They said you should use a `computed` value which derived on the `prop` `editing` and mutate that `computed` value instead.

In addition, whenever you want to change the value of the `prop` `editing`, you should `emit` an event and let the parent component listen to that, then mutate the `editing` value. After the `editing` value is changed, the child component will automatically reflect the change.

Comment: I'm not actually passing `editing` and have edited my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then, there is no reason to use the `props`. That `editing` property should be a property of the data object instead. When you use the `data` object to manage the `editing` state, the warning is definitely gone. I'm sure about that.

Comment: I'm also sure that's correct. And I just recalled reading something about validating data attributes...

Comment: Well then, if my answer did help, you might consider accepting it or just voting. It would be very nice of you to do that.